# Forcing a cast in a generic class

Tags: c#

The compiler is not letting me do a potentially unsafe cast. I'd like to know how to tell it to shut up.

```
List<T> _list = new List<T>();

B getFirst() { return (B) _list[0]; }
```

Is this possible, or do I have to write

```
B b = _myList[0] as B;
Debug.Assert( b != null );
return b;
```

I thought the point of explicit casts was to do unsafe operations. Strange that it's not allowed.

Comment: Cast it to `object` first, then `B`.

Comment: `I thought the whole point of explicit casts was to do unsafe operations` Your assumptions are wrong.

Comment: @L.B Care to elaborate?

Comment: Bit whiffy in here. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast it to `object` first and then to `type B` like (as already been commented)

```
return (B) (object) _list[0];
```

OR

Try casting it in safe way like below. Check for nullity before returning but casting to `object` and then to the actual type would be more general approach.

```
B getFirst() 
{ 
    B b = _list[0] as B;
    if (b != null) 
    { 
        return b; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a type constraint to your class:

```
class Foo<T> where T: B { }
```

Comment: I cannot add that constraint. The constraint that I need is actually `where B : T`, which is not allowed, and wouldn't make the cast safe anyway. Therefore, the compiler cannot guarantee type safety in this case.

Comment: So the cast you need is contravariant? i.e `(string) new object()`?

Comment: @MeirionHughes 1) That's probably an incorrect use of "contravariance." 2) All derived-to-base casts are implicit, so the only non-numerical and non-user-defined explicit casts are base-to-derived. However, the constraint `where B : T` is needed to establish the relationship that B is derived from T (and ensure that `_list` can contain objects of B. Currently this is specified only in the docs.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to tell the compiler, "trust me, I know what I am doing", the only solution is to cast it to `object` first, then to `B` as the accepted answer states.

As a general rule, `object` can be cast to *anything* without the compiler getting in the way, it defers to the runtime to figure out if that cast is legitimate (a dynamic cast).

Casting is used to supply additional information to the compiler when type information has been lost, or if there is a conversion that exists and you are trying to tell the compiler to use that conversion. The compiler isn't letting you cast because type information isn't missing (it knows the type is `T`) and no conversion exists for `T` to `B` so the compiler stops. The compiler is actually trying to do you a favor by saying type T isn't always type B, but you just happen to have things in such a way that it works out like that at run time.

This is one of the slightly confusing aspects of C#: static casts and dynamic casts use identical syntax. Languages like F# use different syntax, like `:>` and `:?>` or VB.NET's `DirectCast`.

Comment: I stand by my statement that explicit casting is for doing unsafe things. Casting an `object` received from who-knows-where is an unsafe thing that simply had the benefit of being common pre-generics. Casting a float to an int is another unsafe thing that is common. I don't see why the compiler lets me cast a base class to a derived type (another unsafe thing), but not a generic type to some other type.