# How do you cast a Unity.Object into a generic class member?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a decades-old C programmer.  Unity is my first foray into modern C and I find myself pleasantly surprised - but some of the subtleties of the language have escaped me.

First a technical question:  What is the right way to store a Unity Object in a generic class?  In the example below I get the following error:

```
Assets/scripts/MediaTest.cs(49,44): error CS0030: Cannot convert type `UnityEngine.Texture2D' to `T'
```

Second the real question:  What is a better approach to loading a set of textures?

Thanks in advance for your help

```
/*
 * MediaTest.cs
 *
 * Pared down generic class test
 *
 */

using System.Collections;                   // Load IEnumerable
using System.Collections.Generic;           // Load Dictionary
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;       // Load Regex
using UnityEngine;                          // Load UnityEngine.Object

public class MediaTest<T> : IEnumerable where T : UnityEngine.Object {
    private Dictionary<string, MediaContent> _dict =
        new Dictionary<string, MediaContent>();

    private class MediaContent {
        public string path { get; set; }
        public T item { get; set; }

        public MediaContent(string path, T item) {
            this.path = path;
            this.item = item;
        }
    }

    // Indexer to return a UnityEngine.Object by filename
    public T this[string name] {
        get { return (T)_dict[name].item; }
    }

    // Convert a path to just the filename
    public string Basename(string path) {
        return new Regex(@"^.*/").Replace(path, "");
    }

    // Iterate through the filenames (keys) to the stored objects
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
        foreach (string name in _dict.Keys) {
            yield return name;
        }
    }

    // Read in the Resource at the specified path into a UnityEngine.Object
    public void Load(string path, bool load=false) {
        string name = Basename(path);
        if (this.GetType() == typeof(Media<Texture2D>) && IsStill(name)) {
            T item = (load) ? (T)Resources.Load<Texture2D>(path) : null;
            _dict[name] = new MediaContent(path, item);
            return;
        }
        if (this.GetType() == typeof(Media<AudioClip>) && IsAudio(name)) {
            T item = (load) ? (T)Resources.Load<AudioClip>(path) : null;
            _dict[name] = new MediaContent(path, item);
            return;
        }
    }

    // The real code uses Regex.Match on the file extension for supported types
    public bool IsStill(string name) { return true; }
    public bool IsAudio(string name) { return true; }
}
```

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497396/forcing-a-cast-in-a-generic-class the following change appears to work:
```
            T item = (load) ? Resources.Load<Texture2D>(path) as T : null;
```
Is this legit?

Comment: Doesn't `Resources.Load` anyway already return the given type? You could afaik simply use `T item = load ? Resources.Load<T>(path) : null;` without these specific type checks around it...

Comment: Resources.Load returns type <Texture2D> while T matches type <MediaTest<Texture2D>>

Comment: Nope .. you pass in type `Texture2D` so `Resources.Load<Texture2D>(path)` returns a `Texture2D`

Comment: That is correct.  The problem happens with the assignment to the value (T item).  T evaluates to type (MediaTest<Texture2D>) which does not match (<Texture2D>) and throws the compiler error noted in the original post.

Comment: Ok some things I don't understand: Why if this class is `MediaTest<T>` you try to compare it to a `this.GetType == Media<Texture2D>`? This is no `Media` but a `MediaTest`. Next if you implement a `MediaTest<Texture2D>` then `T` obviously is a `Texture2D` .. if your `T` says it is a `MediaTest<T>` then I guess you implement it wrong since it would be like `public class Example : MediaTest<MediaTest<Texture2D>>` which isn't quite what you want here

Comment: Hmmm, it must be late at night.  I just tested it again and got a different response:
Debug.Log("Typeof(T) = " + typeof(T));
now prints "Typeof(T) = UnityEngine.Texture2D"
I must have fixed this when I added "where T : UnityEngine.Object

Comment: You are right, "typeof(Media<Texture2D>" should have read "typeof(MediaTest<Texture2D>".  I have simplified it to "typeof(Texture2D)" as you suggest.

Comment: T can be any Unity object  so you cannot convert a Texture2D to T. For example if T is a  Material you're asking the compiler to convert a Texture2D to a Material. This can't be done. It seems to me that you should just replace T with a Unity Object and don't use generics. To your second question, can you give more details on the purpose of this script?

Comment: Ok, I found the error.  this.GetType() returns "Media'1[UnityEngine.Texture2D]" while typeof(T) returns "Texture2D".  I should have used typeof(T)

Comment: Thanks for your patience in helping me work through this!  The second question is "What is the right approach to load assets from a Resources folder". For example assume there is a folder of textures for a particular purpose Assets/Resources/textures/buildings/*.jpg.  The code can read them in several ways:  it can read a list from a JSON file, use System.IO to scan the folder for resources, or hard-code the names in the script.  What is the religiously correct way to pull in a set of 'things'?

Comment: the right for the `Resources` folder approach by Unity itself is found in the [best practices -> section 3 Resources folder](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7) => **Don't use it!** ;) However as said I think you could just go `Resources.Load<T>(path);` since it already returns a `T`. You don't need the additional checks around it. If you need them You can still check `if(typeof(T) == typeof(Texture2D) || typeof(T) == typeof(AudioClip))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code with updates from the comments.  Thanks derHugo!

```
    public void Load(string path, bool load=false) {
        // Translate the filesystem path to a Resources relative path by removing both
        // The */Resources prefix and the filename extention
        Regex re_path = new Regex(@".*/Resources/");
        Regex re_ext = new Regex(@"\.\w+$");
        string relpath = re_ext.Replace(re_path.Replace(path, ""), "");

        // Create an asset name from the path
        string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(relpath);

        // Skip this file if it doesn't match our type
        if (    (typeof(T) == typeof(Texture2D) && IsStill(path)) ||
             // (typeof(T) == typeof(Video) && IsVideo(path)) ||
                (typeof(T) == typeof(AudioClip) && IsAudio(name))) {
            T item = (load) ? Resources.Load(relpath) as T : null;
            _dict[name] = new MediaContent(path, item);
        }
    }
```